# How to find the global extrema of unbounded continuous function?

Tags: calculus, optimization

What is the largest value of $f(x,y)=x^2e^{-(x^2+y^2)}$ if $(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2$?

We have that $f'_x=2x(1-x^2)e^{-(x^2+y^2)}$ and $f'_y=-2x^2ye^{-(x^2+y^2)}$. Setting $f'_x=0$ and $f'_y=0$ we get the critical points $(0,y)$, where $y\in\mathbb{R}$, $(1,0)$ and $(-1,0)$. Further $f(0,y)=0$ and $f(1,0)=f(-1,0)=1/e$.

The largest value should be $1/e$ since we can see that from the function that $f(x,y)\rightarrow 0$ as $(x^2+y^2)\rightarrow \infty$. But how do I prove this?

Comment: You can simplify the function by substituting $t=x^2$ and $s=y^2.$ Then you maximize $te^{-t-s}$ for $s,t\ge 0.$ Derivatives are  simpler.

Answer (score 1):

This particular case is easier than most since
$$
f(x,y) = x^2e^{-x^2} \cdot e^{-y^2}
$$
factors as the product of a nonnegative function of $x$ alone and a nonnegative function of $y$ alone; therefore the two factors can be maximized separately to find the maximum of the overall function.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you,  but the minimum value is 0 how about proving the largest value?

Comment: The largest value you can determine separately for each factor: $ y=0$ and  $x=\pm 1.$

Comment: Sorry I meant maximized—edited